# How can I get the program to loop to the top?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

OK, I am very new to Android and C#. Just started today in fact. I normally program in VB, but anyway I was trying MonoDroid out and after a couple of small tutorials I tried something on my own. What I want is that there are two radio buttons on the canvas. And a disabled button, it only gets enabled when you click on one of the radio buttons. Funnily, you have to code the radio buttons to uncheck when the other one is clicked unlike in windows forms, or I'm missing someting. But I managed that. And when you press the button 'Next' it goes to the next page.

This is my code for the above:

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {

        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        RadioButton radSilent1 = FindViewById<RadioButton>(Resource.Id.radSilent);
        RadioButton radVibrate1 = FindViewById<RadioButton>(Resource.Id.radVibrate);
        Button button1 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnNext);
        radSilent1.Click += delegate
        {
            button1.Enabled = true;
            if (radSilent1.Checked == true)
                radVibrate1.Checked = false;
            else if (radVibrate1.Checked == true)
                radSilent1.Checked = false;
            {
            }
        };
        radVibrate1.Click += delegate
        {
            button1.Enabled = true;
            if (radVibrate1.Checked == true)
                radSilent1.Checked = false;
            else if (radSilent1.Checked == true)
                radVibrate1.Checked = false;
            {
            }
        };
        // Set our view from the "secondry" layout resource
        button1.Click += delegate { SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Secondry); };
    }
```

This brings up the second canvas. Where I have another button 'Back'. When I press that button it brings me to the first screen but the above code doesn't work. I press the two radio buttons and both are checked, and the button doesn't enable either. Why does this happen? Remember I am very new to this sorry. lol
Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you detaching your Click handlers in the onPause?

Comment: Err.. come again? lol I'm very new to this I have no idea what you mean. Thats all the code I have at the moment. Sorry. And thanks for the help =].

Comment: I think @sound has found your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is that when you have used new layout (`SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Secondry)`) you have lost all attached event handlers that was initialized in `OnCreate(Bundle bundle)`. To solve this problem you need to create 2 methods something like `InitializeMainView()` and `InitializeSecondView()` where attach handlers to controls events on selected layout. And after changing layout you just call init method for selected view.

**But i think that the best solution will be to create new separate activity for second view.**

Comment: hmm I almost understand you. I'm used to Windows Forms. So is a new activity like a new form? And how would I call the new activity? I don't really understand how to exactly do that. =S lol. Ohh and what I am doing with the Radio Buttons is that correct or is there another better way to do this? Thanks

Comment: Dont know what to tell you, if you even dont know such basics. I recommend you to watch this tutorials to get some knowledge. It helped me on the beginning http://vimeo.com/20405301

Comment: OK, lol, thanks for the link. But like I said I just started MonoDroid. Anyways Thanks.

Comment: I did not want to injure you, I just noticed that this site is for asking some real questions and not wiki information that you can find on the first page of google results.

Comment: Yeah, I guess, I actually was thinking that myself, that instead of asking what and how to do a new Activity, I search it myself but you've just said it. Again, Thanks.